# How can I get the value of a listBox item in a context menu?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to get the **value** of a listBox item selected by means of a context menu. I've searched for a solution and I've seen some answers but none of them really answered my question. All other attempts I tried just gave me the name of the class used to bind the data.
This is the XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="pubKeyListBox" Height="150" Margin="0,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu" >
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Name="email" Header="send via email" Click="email_Click" />
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Name="delete" Header="delete" Click="delete_Click" />
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding pubKey}" FontSize="24" Width="250"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and the code behind:

```
private void email_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        ListBoxItem selectedKey= this.pubKeyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as MenuItem).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;

        int selectedItem= pubKeyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(selectedKey);
        string fileName = pubKeyListBox.Items[selectedItem].ToString();
    }
```

After that, fileName contains the string "Vault.publicKey", where publicKey, as said, is the name of the class used to bind the data.

Could you please help me out with this thing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `DataContext` should contain the object bound to your ListBoxItem. Assuming `Vault` is your object and `publicKey` is the bound member:

```
string fileName = ( ( ( sender as MenuItem ).DataContext ) as Vault ).publicKey;
```

Comment: Great! You definitely solved my problem.
I was focused on something that was not leading me to the right way.
Thanks!